# Можно ли добавлять или заменять картинки на сайте через админ панель

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет! Я новичок и мне хотелось бы узнать, возможно ли (допустим заказчику) просто заходить в админ панель (или куда-то еще) и таким образом заменять картинки на сайте или их добавлять, предположим сайт-визитка фотографа. Или любой другой способ, кроме того, чтобы влезать в код и там менять эту картинку. Буду очень рад, если подскажите!

upd: Пришла в голову идея. Нельзя ли это осуществить через текстолайт?

Comment: именно так и работает вордпресс

Comment: И текстолайт к WordPress не имеет никакого отношения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Textolite создан специально для таких нужд

Из официального описания:

> Система для редактирования сайтов, основанных на статических HTML-файлах. Ориентирована на небольшие сайты, требующие периодического обновления. Все изменения на сайте сохраняются прямо в HTML-файлах, что избавляет от необходимости иметь сервер базы данных. Не требует какой-либо интеграции с сайтом, достаточно разместить каталог с системой в корне сайта.

> Основной особенностью Textolite является визуальный редактор с
> возможностью редактировать содержимое сайта без каких-либо форм ввода.
> Для более серьезных изменений предусмотрен редактор исходного кода с
> подсветкой синтаксиса и нумерацией строк. Есть также удобный файловый
> менеджер с функцией многопоточной пакетной загрузки файлов на сервер.

Answer (score 0):

> Я новичок и мне хотелось бы узнать, возможно ли (допустим заказчику)
> просто заходить в админ панель (или куда-то еще) и таким образом
> заменять картинки на сайте или их добавлять, предположим сайт-визитка
> фотографа. Или любой другой способ, кроме того, чтобы влезать в код и
> там менять эту картинку.

Именно для этого служит любая CMS и WordPress не исключение.

CMS - Content management system, Система управления контентом (содержимым).